# HOW TO SET WINDOW BACKGROND IN URSINA ENGINE (PYTHON)

Tags: python, background, ursina

I can't set my game's window backgroun image.

This is what I have tried:

```
mainbg = Sky(texture = 'Assets/ruined_city_main_bg')
```

But that was incomprehensible and scary.
Also I have tried:

```
mainbg = Entity(parent = camera.ui, '''All other arguments''', texture = 'Assets/ruined_city_main_bg', position = (0, 0))
```

The "ENTITY BG" is not showing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see it because you didn't give it a model. Try adding `model='quad'`.

```py
mainbg = Entity(parent=camera.ui, model='quad', texture='ruined_city_main_bg')
```

Comment: Oh... I forgot )

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are not setting the file extension.

For example:
*ruined_city_main_bg.png*

where **.png** is an image extension.

or try:

**skybox_image = load_texture("sky_sunset.jpg")**

**Sky(texture=skybox_image)**

Don't forget the file extension.